# How to fix this eslint error after installing my react application

Tags: reactjs, eslint

[image: I was installing my react application and after running npm start i noticed the error below in the screenshot.]

[eslint] Plugin "react" was conflicted between "package.json » eslint-config-react-app » C:\Users\Teke\Desktop\Projects\lilayi_lodge_demo\client\node_modules\eslint-config-react-app\base.js" and "BaseConfig » C:\Users\Teke\Desktop\Projects\lilayi_lodge_demo\Client\node_modules\eslint-config-react-app\base.js".

Comment: the name of the project in package.json is **client** and you named it **Client** with capital **C**

Comment: change your folder name to **client** and make sure in package.json it's the same **client**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have used inconsistent casing when navigating to your project with your terminal. **cd** into the directory of your React project using the correct casing.
you can  :

**1-** Open your shell and cd into the directory using the correct casing.

**2 -** If you use Visual Studio code, you can use the `code .` command to open the current folder in your code editor.